# How to get APK file downloaded by Beta By Crashlytics app when I use Fabric for distributing my app.?

Tags: android, automated-tests, apk, google-fabric

I distributed my app through Fabric using Beta platform.
Now My testers need to have APK file for automating test cases. Where can testers find APK file which was downloaded by Beta by Crashlytics app?

Comment: Thanks. There isn't a public URL for downloading the APK through Beta.